# Dropdown selection in IE 11 is not working

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I am an automation tester and I have automated the dropdown selection. I have a set of elements in a dropdown . I am storing all the values in the dropdown using the below code(I am using the Xpath)

```
ListItem item = "/container[@caption='selectbox']/listitem[@text='" + comboItem + "']";
```

As a recent change, our developers have added null value for the first element of a dropdown. Because of this I am getting error in my code and so dropdown selection functionality is not working. By any way is there a chance to catch the null value stored in the List and continue to the store the next value of the dropdown in the list.

I am using the below code to select an element from a dropdown and I am getting error in the above line that has been described in main part of question.

```
public void SelectfromSelecttag(SelectTag selectTag, string comboItem)
    {
        try
        {                               
            int attemptsToSelect =0;
            int maxAttemps = 3;
            while(attemptsToSelect != maxAttemps)
            {
                selectTag.EnsureVisible();
                selectTag.Click(Location.CenterRight, 1000);    
                ListItem item = "/container[@caption='selectbox']/listitem[@text='" + comboItem + "']";                                         
                Delay.Milliseconds(1000);
                item.Select();
                item.MoveTo();
                item.Click();
                string itemtext = item.Text;
                if(itemtext == comboItem)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    attemptsToSelect++;
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Instance.ErrorLog ("Unable to find Select Item: " + comboItem + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is far too little code here. Where did they add the null value? Where is the error occurring?

Comment: I have added the code that I am using. Basically I am trying to select an element from a dropdown, the developers have added null value in every first element of a dropdown list. Hope this clears your questions